# Deleting li using Node.remove() in JavaScript is not working

Tags: javascript, removechild

I am currently trying to delete li by clicking deleteButton.
This is my full JS code.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const savedList = document.getElementById('savedList');
const doneList = document.getElementById('doneList');

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = document.getElementById('input').value;
  li.id = li.innerText;
  li.isDone = false;
  li.isDone ? doneList.append(li) : savedList.append(li);

  const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  deleteButton.innerText = 'x';
  deleteButton.id = 'deleteButton';
  li.append(deleteButton);

  li.addEventListener('click', () => {
    li.isDone ? (li.isDone = false) : (li.isDone = true);
    li.isDone ? doneList.append(li) : savedList.append(li);
  });

  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const targetToDo = event.currentTarget.parentNode;
    console.log(targetToDo.parentNode);
    targetToDo.parentNode.remove(targetToDo);
    targetToDo.remove();
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="input" type="text" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<ul id="savedList"></ul>
<ul id="doneList"></ul>
```

However, other lis except targetToDo are being deleted. I've tried debugging with console.log but targetToDo and its parentNode is okay. I can see li for a targetToDo and ul for its parentNode. How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What happens when you log `targetToDo`?

Comment: Please add the rest of your markup/code to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: I can see <li> that i clicked a deletedButton on is appended.

Comment: can you help us with some template so that it can be easily reproduced? I can see, you are trying to delete the `delete` button inside an event handler for that button?

Comment: I am trying to delete <li>by using delete button. Therefore, i used ' li.append(deleteButton);'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use [event.stopPropagation()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation) at the end of your `deleteButton.addEventListener`. It will fix your problem.

What is happening with your code is as below.

- When you click on `x` button it will invoke click event for that `button` as well as click event of `li`.
- So, first it will invoke click event of `x` & from `deleteButton.addEventListener` it will remove your `li`.
- Then it will invoke click event of `li` and as per code from `li.addEventListener` it will move `li` to other `ul`.
- The `stopPropagation()` method of the [Event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) interface prevents further propagation of the current event in the capturing and bubbling phases.
- So if you use `event.stopPropagation()` in your `deleteButton.addEventListener` then it will prevent further invoke of `li` click event and it won't be able to add `li` again to other `ul`.

Try code below.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const savedList = document.querySelector("#saved-list");
const doneList = document.querySelector("#done-list");

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = document.getElementById('input').value;
  li.id = li.innerText;
  li.isDone = false;
  li.isDone ? doneList.append(li) : savedList.append(li);

  const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  deleteButton.innerText = 'x';
  deleteButton.id = 'deleteButton';
  li.append(deleteButton);

  li.addEventListener('click', () => {
    li.isDone ? (li.isDone = false) : (li.isDone = true);
    li.isDone ? doneList.append(li) : savedList.append(li);
  });

  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const targetToDo = event.currentTarget.parentNode;
    console.log(targetToDo.parentNode);
    // targetToDo.parentNode.remove(targetToDo);
    targetToDo.remove();
    
    // Add below line.
    event.stopPropagation();
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="input" type="text" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<ul id="saved-list"></ul>
<ul id="done-list"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for detailed explanation! It helped me a lot

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

```js
deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const targetToDo = event.currentTarget.parentNode;
    console.log(targetToDo.parentNode);
    setTimeout(() => li.remove(), 0); // The li that will be removed also has the delete button as child and we are inside the event handler of that child. A setTimeout() works here
  });
```

---

### ***Illustration***

Hopefully, following rudimentary setup along with the code in OP for illustration is closer to the needs of the OP.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('#form');
const savedList = document.querySelector("#saved-list");
const doneList = document.querySelector("#done-list");

form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
  const li = document.createElement('li');
  li.innerText = document.getElementById('input').value;
  li.id = li.innerText;
  li.isDone = false;
  li.isDone ? doneList.append(li) : savedList.append(li); //<--- This condition check is insignificant as we are setting it to false in the previous statement

  const deleteButton = document.createElement('button');
  deleteButton.innerText = 'x';
  deleteButton.id = 'deleteButton';
  li.append(deleteButton);

  li.addEventListener('click', () => {
    li.isDone ? (li.isDone = false) : (li.isDone = true);
    li.isDone ? doneList.append(li) : savedList.append(li);
  });

  deleteButton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
    const targetToDo = event.currentTarget.parentNode;
    console.log(targetToDo.parentNode);
    // targetToDo.parentNode.remove(targetToDo);
    // targetToDo.parentNode.remove();
    // targetToDo.remove();
    setTimeout(() => li.remove(), 0);
  });
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

```html
<form id="form">
  <input id="input" type="text" />
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>

<ul id="saved-list"></ul>
<ul id="done-list"></ul>
```

---

### ***`WYSIWYG`*** => ***`WHAT YOU SHOW IS WHAT YOU GET`***

Comment: Nice solution. But can you explain why you need to use `setTimeout`? Why its not working without it? +1 though :)

Comment: With `setTimeout`, we schedule the deletion of the parent on the event-loop so that it happens after the event handlers are done executing. I also left a comment, may be it didn't make that obvious.